# Is there a way to trim transparent areas using Wand (the ImageMagick Python binding)?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

The following code generates error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections.abc
from wand.image import Image, COMPOSITE_OPERATORS, DISTORTION_METHODS, CHANNELS
from wand.drawing import Drawing

wand_imageText = Image(width=1080,
                   height=1080,
                   background='rgb(0,0,0,0)')

with Drawing() as draw:        
    draw.font = 'Impact'
    draw.font_size = 100
    draw.gravity = 'north_west'
    draw.fill_color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 255)' 
    draw.text(0, 0, "Let's rock!")        
    draw(wand_imageText)

wand_imageText.trim(color='rgb(0,0,0,0)',fuzz=0)

wand_imageText.save(filename='C:\\Temp\\Wand_trim_test.jpg')
wand_imageText.close()
```

> File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 865, in wrapped
>       result = function(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 4444, in trim
>       with color or self[0, 0] as color: AttributeError: **enter**

Any way to trim transparency using Wand?

Comment: Try using `rgba` in `wand_imageText.trim(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)',fuzz=0)`. Also use `rgba` in `draw.fill_color = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)' ` That is the way transparent colors are defined in ImageMagick. Sorry I do not know Python Wand. But I presume it will use the same syntax as ImageMagick. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/color.html

Comment: Using rgba() doesn't work.  It still generates the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Wand. But have you posted your full code? I do not see the connection of the error message with what you have coded. Did you add `rgba` to all the places, including `background='rgba(0,0,0,0)'`

Comment: Yes, that's the full code.  It's the trim function that's generating error.  I have used rgba() everywhere.

Comment: Does ImageMagick support trimming by the alpha value?

Comment: `@Coder1979`.What do you mean by trimming by the alpha value? ImageMagick will automatically trim any transparency around the image, if that is what you mean. In fact it looks at each corner and determines how to trim each side. It does not need a color value provided to know what to trim. I am not sure what Imagick does with trim.

Comment: By 'trimming by the alpha value', I mean removing the outer area using the alpha value.

For example, let's say the background color is rgba(0,0,0,0), the text color is rgba(0,0,0,255), and rgba(0,0,0,0) should be used for trimming.

The text occupies the left-top pixel, so that automatic trim color selection cannot be used since that will remove the text, and the trim color must be specified.

Comment: Looks like you found your own solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

The color argument of the trim function must be a wand.color.Color object for the function to work.

The following code, that uses fmw42's suggestion of using rgba(), does trimming using the alpha value.

```
from wand.color import Color

wand_imageText.trim(color=Color('rgba(0,0,0,0)'),fuzz=0)
```